# Are HTML helpers, including for Editor Templates, fully supported in ASP.NET Core 5: and will my Editor Templates code for @Html.EditorFor still work?

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to know IF, in **ASP.NET Core 5 and forward**, Editor Template code, written using .NET Framework 4.8, for @Html.EditorFor and similar stuff, still continue to function/work?  OR, as is typical of Microsoft, we need to have a long learning curve, to learn a new way of doing the same old things, to produce the same results?

***Summary:***  Are HTML Helpers backwards compatible in ASP.NET Core 5?  Will old code still compile (especially Editor Templates) OR No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it still work in asp.net-core-5.0,you can see my demo below.

Model:

```
 public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TestChildModel> TestChildModels { get; set; }
  
}

public class TestChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

TestChildModel.cshtml

[image]

```
@model TestChildModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <input asp-for="Id" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input asp-for="Name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input asp-for="Count" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Count" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index view:

```
@model TestModel

<form  method="post"  asp-action="Test">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.TestChildModels.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestChildModels[i])
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Soumettre" />
</form>
```

TestController:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var tModel = new TestModel
        {
            Name = "Test 1",
            TestChildModels = new List<TestChildModel>
        {
            new TestChildModel {Id = 1, Name = "Child 1", Count = 0},
            new TestChildModel {Id = 2, Name = "Child 2", Count = 0},
            new TestChildModel {Id = 2, Name = "Child 3", Count = 0},
        }
        };


        return View(tModel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(TestModel testModel)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Test Result:

[image]